# google cloud storage mySql query reads only a few hundred lines per second

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql

I have set up a database with a table of approximately 100GB. I use 4cpu and 15GB ram on the gcs. When I make a query I can see from the read/write operations dashboards that only a few hundred lines are read per second which will take forever to complete.

the query is done on DBeaver, it is not a complicated query as can be seen from the picture attached. I simply do not understand why it is so slow??

the query is simply this:

"""INSERT INTO analytics_agg (
hash,
product,
interface,
click_time_0,
click_time_5,
click_time_10,
click_time_30,
click_time_60)
SELECT
hash,
product,
interface,
count(case when click_time=0 then 1 else 0 end) ,
count(case when click_time=5 then 1 else 0 end) ,
count(case when click_time=10 then 1 else 0 end) ,
count(case when click_time=30 then 1 else 0 end) ,
count(case when click_time=60 then 1 else 0 end)
FROM analytics
group by hash,product,interface """
[image]

Comment: Hi, please consider posting a version of the picture that doesn't include your Project Name and Cloud SQL instanance name. Notice that this information can be considered as PII and not suitable to share through public forums such as StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

As you're selecting from one table and inserting in another, the selection from the first table has a large impact on the final insertion rate and performance.

Try to create the following index, which should optimize the selection query and improve the overall performance of the insertion:

```
ALTER TABLE `analytics` ADD INDEX `analytics_idx_hash_product_interface` (`hash`,`product`,`interface`);
```

Comment: this is a good idea indeed it tried it. Probem is that for this query, speed cranks up only to about 2000lines per second which again will take way too long (500 million lines) so something is going on under the hood that makes it crawl and I don't get what it is

Comment: The answer is very good. How are you making the connection from DBeaver to Cloud SQL (Cloud SQL Proxy, directly using secure connection)? Does increasing the instance's tier improves the query performance?